# Android - rotate bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I need rotate pictures to portrait. I made this method using exif:

```
    private static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap) throws java.io.IOException{
    int width = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch(orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
        }
    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 || orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    }
    else {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    }
}
```

In case of ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 or ORIENTATION_NORMAL this method works fine.

In case of ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 or ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 this method stretches the picture in the width dimension. I tried to switch the width with the height and the application has crashed.

I need this method to rotate the bitmap and don't loss quality or scale it had before.

How can i do that?

Comment: Why rotate the bitmap and not the View displaying the bitmap?

Comment: That would be good also

Comment: imageView.setRotation(angle); - see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float))

Comment: post what you tried with width/height inversion and the resulting error.